# Why "if" is not doing anything in this boolean method?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import Scanner
public class review{ //name of the program
    public static void main(String[]args){ // main statement
        Scanner i=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String b=i.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a letter");
        char c=i.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Answer is "+test1(b,c));
    }
     public static boolean test1(String a, char b){
         boolean result= true;
         for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
             if(a.charAt(i)==b)
                 result =true;
             else
                 result=false;
         return result;
     }
 }
```

this program is looking for checking the char is in the string or not.

> Hello, E = true
>   Hello, a = false

Comment: Note that in addition to the answers so far you'd also need to consider case-insensitive comparison for your first example to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this method `test1`, your `for`loop will traverse the whole line although it finds the `letter` into the `string`. so update it like this:

```
public static boolean test1(String a, char b){
         for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++) {
             if(a.charAt(i)==b)
                 return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
```

Because, if the `letter` is found into the `string` you don't need to check further, hence:

```
if(a.charAt(i)==b) // if condition finds true path
    return true; // so return true
```

Note that, `return` statement causes execution to leave the current `function` or tersely current subordinate.

Comment: *so update it method like this* please provide more explanation on *why* the method should be updated like this. Technically, it's right, but OP (and future readers) need to understand the reasons behind this.

Comment: i was adding a break after the first condition and thank you for showing me the right way. i just start using method.

Comment: @Jack, yes `break` statement will also work. To use `break` you need the `boolean result` variable. Study about [return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) and [Control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You're never breaking out of the loop. Consider `"Hello"` and `'e'`

```
 see H: result = false
 see e: result = true
 see l: result = false...
```

`break` from the loop. Or, just use `String.indexOf(char)`

Answer (score 1):

after each check you are changing result, without considering the option the the character is already found.
you can see is in [twentylemon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30822924/1065197).

i just wanted to say something that will be more correct and efficient.
insted of using `break` and return `result` you can do return `true` if the character is found.
in the end of the loop return `false`.

in this way, you dont need the `result` variable and the break.

this is how you write it as i suggested:

```
public static boolean test1(String a, char b)
{
     for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
     {
         if(a.charAt(i)==b)
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

if you will check it, you will see how simple and good it is :)

Comment: Your method always returns `false`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yea oops, i forgot to change the result = true to return true.

Comment: @amitfarag so i don't need "result" anymore, right ?

Comment: @Jack yes, you dont need it in this way